How to determine wedge angles, stagger angles, pitch, and chord for axial turbine mean-line modelling?
I would like to measure the performance and optimize the design of an axial turbine using mean-line modelling. However, most of the optimization codes I found on GitHub require wedge angles, stagger angles, pitch, chord, etc. My question is, how would we even know these parameters beforehand, and if it is sensible to know them, how can we calculate these parameters?

Measure an existing turbine then model it...

For an optimization problem, one generally takes a realistic guess and changes the parameters until the most desired result is achieved. Since most search routines will move away from  nearby worse results, different guesses may yield different local best results (local minimums or maximums).

Is there a manual for the turbine? If so, such parameters might be stated in the manual.
